# Browser-based UML-tool with SVG-support

Tags: uml

I am looking for a tool for creating and hosting UML-diagrams, with the following requirements (in order of priority):

1. It must support standalone on-premise installation. Due to company policy I will not be able to use an externally hosted tool.
2. It must be actively maintained and officially released (no beta-versions).
3. It must have a browser-based, graphical editor (not text-based, like http://yuml.me). I want it to be as easily accessible as possible.
4. It must support embedding diagrams

   1. in SVG-format
   2. or a lossless format like PNG,
   3. but no JPEG or the likes.
5. It should provide an editing history, with support for rollback.

   - It would be nice if it provided some kind of *forking*-feature, so that I can develop alternative versions of the same diagram easily.

[Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) sounds like a good candidate, but it does not fulfill the first criterion.

I am not necessarily looking for a single-product solution. If anyone has patched together a working solution using different tools, I would like to hear about it. It does not have to be for free.

Comment: plantuml and a solution from my company BITPlan for model exchange could be part of what you need. I'm not sure whether there is already a graphical frontend for plantuml.

Answer (score -1):

Try [magicdraw](http://www.nomagic.com), a commercial tool from *nomagic*. Using it, you can generate an html-based presentation of your model and host it.